# Drawing sawtooth graph with lines() in R

Tags: r, plot, lines

I'd like to draw a graph which has a sawtooth shape, connecting some points.The problem is that when I use lines() I can't get the correct pattern

These are the points:

[image]

I'd like to get the following lines (red line):

[image]

and

[image]

With lines() I don't get the correct plot. I tried these codes:

A)

```
lines(opsOK$X, opsOK$VariableCost, lty=2, col=cols[2])
points(opsOK$X, opsOK$VariableCost)
```

[image]

B)

```
lines(opsOK$X, opsOK$VariableCost, type="s", lty=2, col=cols[2])
points(opsOK$X, opsOK$VariableCost)
```

[image]

Is there a way I can draw these graphs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The data points you have do not form a sawtooth pattern because there are no pair of points sharing the same x value (the vertical drop).  If you want a sawtooth pattern you should add the missing points.

Comment: You're right.. It was as simple as to add new points to the graph. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As R. Schifini pointed out, it's necessary to add the missing points to the graph.